# Why legend in matplotlib only show one string?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to loop legend in python. Here is my code.

```
for i in range(int(np.sqrt(n))):

    x=list(df_vrp.iloc[sol[i],1])

    y=list(df_vrp.iloc[sol[i],2])
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.legend("Truck"+str(i+1),loc='upper left')
```

However, the result is like below. Why the legend can not loop and it only showed one letter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because, `plt.legend` requires an `iterable` with the names, so why not try this...

```py
legend=[]

for i in range(int(np.sqrt(n))):

    x=list(df_vrp.iloc[sol[i],1])

    y=list(df_vrp.iloc[sol[i],2])
    plt.plot(x,y)
    legend.append(f"Truck{i+1}")

plt.legend(legend,loc='upper left')
```